# Object spawner not working right

Tags: rec-room

I am trying to get a skull to respawn when the game starts. For simplicity I just hooked the object spawner up to a button for now. When I click the button the object disappears and reappears a long distance from the object spawner. The tags are the same, it is wired correctly. This is the 3rd object spawner in this room, the others work fine. I took a video to show exactly what I mean. Any help would be appreciated.

Video on YouTube:

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the pivot of your object being way off from the skull. The object spawner always respawns an object such that the pivot is in the middle of the spawner. If you respawn that skull, then go into edit mode on the skull, you should see the origin right in the middle of the object spawner. To fix this, you have a few options:

1. You can select all of the shapes on the skull in edit mode. A contextual menu will pop up with one option that allows you to "center pivot". This will move the pivot of the object into the middle of all the shapes you have selected.
2. You can select all the shapes in edit mode and move them to the pivot.